# Could the TARDIS stop a Weeping Angel?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis, weeping-angels

A Weeping Angel freezes if it is observed, due to quantum shenanigans. The TARDIS  is alive, and is I think, aware of the inhabitants of... herself.

If an Angel entered the TARDIS, is it resonable to assume that they'd always be watched, always be forced to remain statues and therefore could be locked up safe, somewhere in the TARDIS?

Comment: Until it was convenient for the Doctor to have a psychotic, time-eating, 'DID IT JUST MOVE, I SAW IT MOVE' baddie on the loose, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weeping Angels can move inside the TARDIS.  The Doctor Who mini-episode "[Good as Gold](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88e5vGPTVgg)" features an Angel inside the entrance to the TARDIS.  That Angel is able to move successfully when none of the humanoids watch it.

Comment: I've just watched it....I'd question the cannonicity, if that meant anything in the whoniverse. Also, it moves when the tardis sparks, so possibly when She cannot see it either. Anyway, good catch.

Comment: Link is broken. This one: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_TfU8bTpqo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_TfU8bTpqo) appears to be good, if you wish to update the answer.

Comment: @PaulRichter Your link appears to be a private link. Now we have 2 useless links :-)